# HTML5 help, can't figure out errors shown in validator

Tags: html, validation

Using the HTML validator I'm getting two errors I can't quite figure out.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Prime Properties Listing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="prime.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1><img src="primelogo.gif" alt=“PRIMELOGO” height=“100” width=“650”/></h1>
<a href="index.html"><img src="primehomenav.gif" height="25" width="107" alt="Home"/></a> 
<a href="listing.html"><img src="primelistingsbtn.gif" height="25" width="107" alt="listing"/></a> 
<a href="financing.html"><img src="primefinancingnav.gif" height="25" width="107" alt="financing"/></a> 
<a href="contact.html"><img src="primecontactnav.gif" height="25" width="107" alt="contact"/></a>


<h3> Schaumburg Colonial </h3>
<p>This single family home is a two-story colonial on a large lot</p>
<a href="listing.html"><img src="schaumburgthumb.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt=""></a>
<ul>
<li>Four bedrooms</li>
<li>Two and 1/2 baths</li>
<li>Two car garage</li>
<li>Listing#3432535</li>
</ul>

<h3>Libertyville Condo</h3>
<p>New Construction condo in downtown Libertyvilla</p>
<a href="listing.html"><img src="libertyvillethumb.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt=""></a> 
<ul>
<li>Close to train</li>
<li>Two bedrooms,two baths</li>
<li>Two indoor parking spaces</li>
<li>Listing#3432432</li>
</ul>

<div id="footer">
<a href="primeindex.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="listing.html">Listing</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="financing.html">Financing</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>&nbsp;<br>

<small><i>&copy; Copyright "blahblah" blahblah 2012</i></small> <br /><a href="mailto:blahblah@gmail.com">blahblah@gmail.com</a></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

2 errors:

1) Line 11, Column 71: Bad value “100” for attribute height on element img: Expected a digit but saw “ instead.

Syntax of non-negative integer:
One or more digits (0–9). For example: 42 and 0 are valid, but -273 is not.

2)Line 11, Column 71: Bad value “650”/ for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw “ instead.

Syntax of non-negative integer:
One or more digits (0–9). For example: 42 and 0 are valid, but -273 is not.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this

```
alt=“PRIMELOGO” height=“100” width=“650”
```

with

```
alt="PRIMELOGO" height="100" width="650"
```

On line `11`. It looks like you were using a different character for quotations wrapping the attributes.